# SUM a count PL SQL ORACLE

Tags: sql, oracle

im trying to SUM a COUNT in ORACLE SQL, This is my query:

```
SELECT p.cod_profesor, p.pnombre_profesor || ' ' || appat_profesor as NOMBRE,p.sueldo_base,
a.horas_semanales * COUNT(hp.cod_asignatura) AS "HORAS_SEMANALES",
hp.cod_asignatura
FROM profesor p
JOIN horario_profesor hp
ON p.cod_profesor = hp.cod_profesor
JOIN asignatura a
ON hp.cod_asignatura = a.cod_asignatura
GROUP BY p.cod_profesor,p.pnombre_profesor,p.appat_profesor,p.sueldo_base,a.horas_semanales,hp.cod_asignatura
ORDER BY 1;
```

Result:
[Query](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lg3BO.png)

I need to SUM that HORAS_SEMANALES for example from Juan Toledo, him Horas_Semanales must be 80 and not two 40

I was trying to make  a SUM in that count but i cant,

Comment: what is the specific error?

Comment: What does *i can't* mean? Why can't you? You've not clearly explained a problem, provided sample data and the output you want from that data, or asked a question.

Answer (score 0):

I think you want `SUM()` and to fix the `GROUP BY` so `a.horas_semanales` is not an aggregation key but is instead aggregated:

```
SELECT p.cod_profesor, p.pnombre_profesor || ' ' || appat_profesor as NOMBRE, p.sueldo_base,
      SUM(a.horas_semanales) AS "HORAS_SEMANALES", hp.cod_asignatura
FROM profesor p JOIN
     horario_profesor hp
     ON p.cod_profesor = hp.cod_profesor JOIN
     asignatura a
     ON hp.cod_asignatura = a.cod_asignatura
GROUP BY p.cod_profesor, p.pnombre_profesor, p.appat_profesor, p.sueldo_base, hp.cod_asignatura
ORDER BY 1;
```